# How do I access MediaPlayerElement in a parent SplitView?

Tags: mvvm, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm working on creating a radio app for Windows 10 on the UWP platform.  I have a SplitView, with the right side (the SplitView Content) with a bottom margin.  Down the bottom of the window I have a MediaPlayer (with TransportControls) down the bottom of the window.

The list of radio stations to play from are in a frame, which loads a certain page.

My question is, when I click on the radio station that I want to play, how do I set the source for this control, which exists in the parent window?  I've tried to make a MediaPlayer object in the code behind and then maybe bind to that but I can't bind the physical XAML UI control to the MediaPlayer object.  And even still, I can't access this object from another page in the app.

I'm a bit lost. Any help would be awesome :D

Answer (score 1):

Do you use MvvMLight library ?
Because the solution in your case can be the Messaging logic.
Like the following code :

You create a message class with a Radio property (your business class) :

```
public class PlayRadioMessage
{
    public PlayRadioMessage(Radio radio)
    {
        this.Radio = radio;
    }

    public Radio Radio { get; set; }
}
```

In your command on radio items (when click on a radio)

```
Messenger.Default.Send(new PlayRadioMessage(radio))
```

In your parent (SplitView content or MediaPlayer parent), you receive the message :

```
Messenger.Default.Register<PlayRadioMessage>(this, this.OnPlayRadio);
private void OnPlayRadio(PlayRadioMessage) {
// Set the source of your mediaPlayer with the radio property of your Message
}
```

Don't forget to unregister from messaging on unload of your view (if messaging is used in a View) :

```
Messenger.Default.Unregister(this);
```

Sorry for my english, I'm french :)  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I'll try that tonight.  By the way, your english is on point :)